# Retrieving tens of thousands from a number with regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Any idea how to make a regex that retrieves tens of thousands from a number ?

What I mean is for all positive integers should return the integer divided by 10000 rounded down.
For 0 that would be 0, for 999 would be 0 too, for 12345678 would be 1234, and so on.

I was thinking of a series of conditions like

"if the number has between 1 and 4 digits return 0 else if the number has 5 digits return the 1st one else if the number has 6 return first 2 and so on".

My numbers are between 1 and 999 millions.

It's for a `RewriteRule` in `htaccess`.

Comment: I know. I was thinking of a series of conditions like "if the number has between 1 and 4 digits return 0 else if the number has 5 digits return the 1st one else if the number has 6 return first 2 and so on". My numbers are between 1 and 999 millions.

Comment: which langage r u using..also you need to include the info into your question that you just provided in the comment!

Comment: Just did, thank you. Sorry about that, new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple answer, I am unsure why your question was marked down.  I could only write it in VB or C# for you, but you may be able to get the point.

```
Dim rmTens As String = Regex.Replace(Regex.Match(input, "([\d,. ]*)(?:\d[,. ]*){4}(?:$|[^\d,. ])").Groups(1).Value, "[,. ]", "")
If rmTens = "" Then rmTens = "0"
```

This is a quickie, but it captures all digits, commas, decimals, and whitespace (all valid numeric characters) up until a match of three digits (allowing malformed messiness), not followed by any other numeric allowable values.